# Unexpected result in sprintf()

Tags: c, printf, endianness

Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

```
char pcMessage[255];
iMsgAllocatedLength=255;
unsigned long long ullRecordID = 135290303ULL;
sprintf_s(pcMsg, iMsgAllocatedLength, "%08X;%llu", ullRecordID, ullRecordID);
```

Gives the following result

> **08105DBF**;581067426850930688;

While

```
sprintf_s(pcMsg, iMsgAllocatedLength, "%010llu;%08X;", ullRecordID, ullRecordID);
```

Gives the expected result

> 0135290303;**08105DBF**

Please note that I just reverse the order, and note also that
 581067426850930688 is **08105DBF**00000000

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Printing an `unsigned long long` using `%X` format specifier is undefined behavior, because `sprintf` expects an `unsigned int` for `%X`. It produces correct results when you switch around the specifiers by an unfortunate coincidence. The behavior on different platforms may not be the same.

Use `%llX` to print the value:

```
sprintf_s(pcMsg, iMsgAllocatedLength, "%08llX;%llu", ullRecordID, ullRecordID);
```

Answer (score 4):

You pass `unsigned long long` for `"%x"` specifier, which expects `unsigned int`. Thus your code involves undefined behaviour. Nobody knows what will happen in that case and you cannot count on anything. It may work, or it may crash, or maybe print part of what you expect, or print garbage, or absolutely whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Without any length modifier, a `%X` directive expects the corresponding argument to be of type `unsigned int`.  In your case, the corresponding argument is actually an `unsigned long long int`, which is unlikely to be -- and in your case apparently isn't -- the same type.  You want to use `%llX` instead:

```
sprintf_s(pcMsg, iMsgAllocatedLength, "%08llX;%llu", ullRecordID, ullRecordID);
```

Note that the version that prints the expected output is wrong, too -- there you're just getting lucky.